# Updating VB.net windows applications over the internet

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows application developed in VB.net 2005. The application is installed in several machines.

Is there anyway when I do any modifications and publish the code it updates in all the machines.

PS: All the machines are connected to internet.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not an "Automatic" way of doing this, but there are various ways that you could try to enhance and automate the process.

1. You could build your own "updater" that polls every X days for an update, and pulls it down.
2. You could use click once to deploy and have the users do the updates.

Answer (score 0):

For an *existing* application, there's nothing automatic out there.  For a *new* application, look into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment.